# Cauchy's integral formula - Self teaching: $\int_C\frac{5z^4-3z^3+2i}{(z-1)^3}dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Hi I'm trying to teach myself Complex analysis and can't find many good examples online. When looking at a past exam paper I stumbled across this question:

Evaluate $$\ \int_C \frac {5z^4-3z^3+2i} {(z-1)^3} dz $$

Where C is any simple closed curve in a counterclockwise direction with z=1 inside C

Any help you can offer would really help out! Thanks

EDIT:
$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n}}\, dz
$$ with
$$
f(z)=5z^4-3z^3+2i, \quad a=1, \quad n=3.
$$
I get the answer to be: 
$$ \frac{2 \pi i}{2!}f^{(2)}(1)=\pi i (60-18)=42 \pi i
$$

Think i may have done this wrong as it seems like an unusually large number?

Comment: Do you know the Residue Theorem?

Comment: @TheCount Thanks for your response. I haven't looked at it yet no

Comment: The answer that has since appeared is good, and what I would have essentially written. When you get to the Residue Theorem, come back to this and check it against that solution, too. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Theorem)
$$
f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}\, dz
$$ with
$$
f(z)=5z^4-3z^3+2i, \quad a=1, \quad n=2.
$$

Comment: hey thanks for your help. Not sure if I'm right but would you mind taking a look at my attempt above?

Comment: @Lauren_Burke You are welcome. Your answer is right!